# Excel Get total number of unique text values based on condition

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

I have a weekly breakdown report that requires I collect the total count of unique value of Agents Audited per Week. I have done some research and have come up with a couple ways to get a unique count (=CountA(Unique(*range of agents*) or =Sumproduct(1/Countif(*range of agents*, *range of agents*). That would work great if I didn't also have to break it down by week. I have attempted to Change the countif function to a Countifs and use a conditional date range but that just provides me with at #Div# error as some of the values in the array generated would be a 0. The finalized data set should look something like this.
[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1auA.png)

Comment: You could add your source data to the Data Model, after which you can create a simple Pivot Table with Distinct Count in the Values field. Failing that, if you wish to do it with formulas it would be useful to know if you have Office 365 or not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Personally, i would prefer to get this done using formulas, If need be I can fall back on the Pivot table. Yes, I do have O365.

Comment: So combine `UNIQUE` with `FILTER`.

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($E$2:$E$20,($F$2:$F$20>=B2)*($F$2:$F$20<B2+7))))
```

to drag

```
=BYROW(B2:B4,LAMBDA(x,COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($E$2:$E$20,($F$2:$F$20>=x)*($F$2:$F$20<x+7))))))
```

to spill.

Result:

[image]